# Trying to understand v-bind within v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Take the below code as an example:

```css
.fav { background:”blue”}
```

```html
<li
  v-for="(book, index) in books"
  :key="book.title"
  :id="this.code + '-' + index"
  :class="{fav: book.isFav}"
>
  {{book.title}} - {{index}}
</li>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    code: "N54234",
    books: [
      { title: "the final empire", isFav: true },
      { title: "the test empire", isFav: false },
      { title: "the first empire", isFav: true },
    ],
  };
}
```

Assuming the `fav: book.isFav` is a ternary operator and the `{}` in `{fav: book.isFav}` is a way of grouping similar to a function, then why:

1. Is it not required on `:id="this.code + '-' + index"`?
2. Does it give an error when `id` is changed to use it like so: `:id="{this.code+'-'+index}"`

   I get the following error in the console where it complains about the dot in `this.code` so `this` is out of scope

   ```
   Error parsing JavaScript expression: Unexpected token '.'
   ```

Comment: Should it just be `code` instead of `this.code`?

Comment: _"Assuming the `fav: book.isFav` is a ternary operator and the `{}` in `{fav: book.isFav}` is a way of grouping similar to a function"_ - why assume that? `{fav: book.isFav}` ls an _object_, just like in regular JS: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes

Comment: `this` refers to the component, not to its data. As you can see, `data` is a function which returns an *object*. So just use `{code}` instead.

Comment: classes and styles can have multiple key-value properties, so the object notation is provided by Vue to make that easier.  It's actually described in the top paragraph of the class/style binding page in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html).  id attribute is much simpler so being able to bind a string is all that's necessary.

Comment: The key takeaways are that **(a)** the values passed to bound attributes are simply JS expressions (with a few exceptions; event listeners can be passed a function call and it will be implicitly wrapped in a function); **(b)** some attributes have multiple _types_ of values that can be bound and which will be given different treatment; `class`, for example, can have a string bound, which will be the class list, or an object, in which case the properties with truthy values will have their keys applied as classes.

Comment: **(c)** All data is in scope in the template; `this` is not needed. This can even be seen in your example, where you refer to `books` in the `v-for`.

Comment: Then... `this` is not "out of scope" in your second example; it is a _parsing_ error: you tried to create an object, and what should have been a property key had a dot in it, which is invalid.

Comment: A note: your CSS is invalid: you have fancy quotes instead of regular quotes, and even so it would be an invalid value for for `background`; remove the quotes entirely.

Comment: I am failing to see how this is about binding "within `v-for`". It seems to be simply a great misunderstanding of how attribute binding works in general.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @jonrsharpe I understand now that I was misinterpreting the { } as a function of Vue when its classic JS. I still don't get how a fav: true can result in a class="fav" and fav:false resolve as class="" or not adding the class at all. Is this a function of Vue ?

Comment: Yes it's a function of Vue (in common with others including Angular), I already pointed you to where it's documented.

Answer (score 1):

I finally understand my mistake. Thank you all for your efforts and the clarifications. I misunderstood the JS Object as a function of Vue. I now understand that an object is passed to the v-bind **:class** and then takes the Boolean value of **isFav** to determine if the class **fav** is to be attached or not. Thank you all again for sharing your expertise.